# How to store default constructor output in string?

Tags: java, eclipse, constructor

```
    public class demo2{

        public demo2() throws FileNotFoundException {
             Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new 
             File("/home/madhu/Desktop/demo.txt"));
             while (scanner.hasNextLine())
                 System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
            demo2 obj = new demo2();
        }
   }
```

new demo2()
gives output as
Data1,200,1000
Data2,201,2000
How to store new demo2() value into String array or how to write to get output in such format ?
I want to store as
st1= Data1,200,1000
st2= Data2,201,2000

Comment: As a suggested learning path, I'd recommend to go through some tutorials on object-oriented programming. The question that immediately came to my mind was "What is a `demo2` instance supposed to represent?" Answering that, you'll probably come up with a better name and software structure.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this.

**ScannerReader.class**

```
public class ScannerReader {

private ArrayList<String> scannerInput;

public ScannerReader() {
    scannerInput = new ArrayList<>();
    readFileInput();
}

private void readFileInput() {
    try {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("src\\date.txt"));
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
            scannerInput.add(scanner.nextLine());
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void printArrayData() {
    for(String line : scannerInput) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}
```

}

**Main.class**

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
     ScannerReader reader = new ScannerReader();
     reader.printArrayData();
  }
}
```